# Typescript dynamic union type of dynamic object properties

Tags: typescript

How can I get a dynamic union type from dynamic object properties.

```
const config = {
  devices: {
    Brand1: ['model1'],
    Brand2: ['model2', 'model3'],
  },
};

export type DeviceBrand = keyof typeof config.devices; // 'Brand1' | 'Brand2'

export type DeviceModel = ___________; // 'model1' | 'model2' | 'model3'
```

What do I need to do to make DeviceModel the union type of all the models from my brands in my object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
const config = {
  devices: {
    Brand1: ['model1'],
    Brand2: ['model2', 'model3'],
  },
} as const;

export type DeviceBrand = keyof typeof config.devices; // 'Brand1' | 'Brand2'

export type DeviceModel = typeof config['devices'][DeviceBrand][number]; // 'model1' | 'model2' | 'model3'

const a: DeviceModel = 'model1' // valid
const b: DeviceModel = 'model4' // type error
```

You need to use the `const` assertion for the config variable so the type is narrowed down to the concrete string values

Comment: Thanks that works, wondering if there is a way to cast the 'as const' after config is imported, I just added the config const here for example purposes, but in reality it is imported from another file where I might not want the as const?

Comment: And another follow up question, is there a way to have an iterable DeviceModel as well?

Comment: You need to use the const assertion when you initialize the arrays, otherwise the arrays would be of type `string[]`.

Comment: To get an iterable of device models the best practice would be to specify them using an `enum`. Otherwise you can just take the values of the `devices` object and flatten them:

`const models = Object.values(config.devices).flat()`