# Typescript Definition File: create dynamic union type by iterating over complex obect

Tags: javascript, typescript

[Typescript dynamic union type of dynamic object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69000828/typescript-dynamic-union-type-of-dynamic-object-properties) is close but doesn't fully cover what I am trying to accomplish.

My project doesn't use typescript directly but we are using .d.ts files to add some typing and autocompletion. We have a giant .json file which lists our database schema. I was hoping to iterate through that json (which is pretty nested) and pick out some specific strings (the models) to be added to a union type. This would let me autocomplete the model in vscode.

So how can I import a json file and iterate/clean it up and then use it in a .d.ts file to create a union type?

Here is what I have tried:

```
const models = [] as const;
schemaLims.data.__schema.types.forEach((type: { name: string }) => {
  models.push(type.name);
});

type modelName = typeof models[number];
type fragArray = [modelName, string];
```

But that did not work.

```
const models = ["containerArray", "aliquot"] as const;
type modelName = typeof models[number];
type fragArray = [modelName, string];
```

does work but is not dynamic.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do - do you want to write code that *generates* a `.d.ts` file, do you want to write code in the `.d.ts` file that generates types, or do you want to write type declarations that somehow reference JSON data?

Comment: I want to create a type declaration in a .d.ts file that references the json data from a schema.json file. It should build a new type based on fields parsed from that schema file.

Comment: That's not possible. A .d.ts file can only statically *declare* types. It cannot dynamically build new types, it doesn't execute any code that can parse a file.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, that is what I was afraid of. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

in you d.ts file

```
import someJson from './locationOfJSONFile'

type AAA = typeof someJson['someKey']
```

keep in mind that if you `import` something in `d.ts` file, the types in the file is no longer global